# How to convert a very small bash script into a single line command

Tags: shell-script

I have a following bash script and it is being executed using popen(/path/to/script, 'r+') from C code and saving result back (Ex: DA00000);
for this, i need to export a bash script file.

I should not use a seperate bash script.

How to write below script in a single line itself as command?

So, i can use this command directly ( Ex:fp = popen(command "r")) in C code.

```
#!/bin/sh
url="$(grep 0x017a /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/device)"

addr="$(echo $url | cut -d/ -f6)"

str="$(head -n1 /sys/bus/pci/devices/$addr/resource | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"

result="${str:${#str} - 8}"

echo $result
```

Comment: I would suggest that you, instead of executing an external shell script, opened the `device` files directly and read from them with your C program.

Comment: But i have to read all devices to find exact match i.e. 0x017a since there are many device file are available.

Comment: notice that your script is broken -- the `/sys/bus/pice/devices/*/device` files do not contain any url or file name; you probably want `grep -l` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your script to a C string and then pass that string directly to the `popen(3)` function.

Notice that `popen(3)` takes a script which will be passed as an argument to `sh -c` (and which can contain any valid shell commands) not just a program name or a command line.

Example:

```
$ perl -e '
     print qq{char *script =\n};
     while(<>){
         s/([\0-\x1f"\\\x7f-\xff])/sprintf "\\x%02x",ord$1/ge;
         print qq{\t"$_"\n}
     }
     print qq{;\n}
' script.sh > script.h
$ cat script.h
char *script =
...
```

Then in your `C` file:

```
#include script.h
     ...
     FILE *fh = popen(script, "r");
```

Comment: May i know how to convert into a C string without using Perl?  because i may not be able to use perl also

Comment: You can do it in `C` ;-). I think that there are already programs like `bin2c` or such, that perl thing was a quick and dirty example.

Comment: but you would probably be better off by just doing the whole thing in `C`; that script is defective and overly complicated, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with two pass:

first part (url+addr)

```
awk -F/ '/0x017a/ {print $6}' /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/device
```

second part

```
awk 'NR==1 { print substr($1,1,length($1)-8;}' /sys/bus/pci/devices/$addr/resource
```

I am not quiet sure this is a good way to address the problem.

Comment: I executed  above command but didnt work as expected.

Comment: Your comment doesn't help me as expected.